# share entities between maven projects

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-3

I'm migrating one monolithic project to a microservices architecture and just for sake of make things work, I'm basically copy-pasting the model and repository classes between the projects. Turns out that I know that I can create one maven module with these classes and add it as dependency of any other project, but one thing comes to my mind: These classes are mapping of my database, and in this monolithic project, my `application.yml` contains all the info related to database access. If I decouple it and put this models and repositories to a separated module, where should this config lives? inside the module, inside the project that have it as dep.?

Ok, I tried a lot of things, and this is where I'm now:
I created a maven project that depends on spring boot jpa starter and added the classes (models, repos, etc) and added this project as dependency of another bigger project, but I'm seeing this error now:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project github: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.inkdrop:github:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.inkdrop:commons:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in https://repo.spring.io/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of spring-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

it this case, `commons` is the project I want to add as depedency of `github` since it contains the models and repos

Here is my `commons` `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.inkdrop</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Commons files</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>com.inkdrop.App</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>
                                spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
                    </artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-loaded.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: As you see from the error message, it is trying to look for your commons project from Spring's Maven repository and obviously it is not there. Do you have your own repository that the commons project is built into?

Comment: no, I don't. I ran `mvn install` on the commons projects, and now the `github` project found the commons library. Is this right, maybe? or should I go with a repository?

Comment: It's now found from your local repository (on your HDD), as you built it there. This is ok, while you're building the project on your own computer. Rest depends on how you deploy it to next environment (integration, test or production).

Comment: but if I create a .war file for the `github` module, would it also compile and include the `commons`?

Comment: Yes, if you have commons as a compile dependency of github, commons will get packaged inside the /WEB-INF/lib directory of the WAR archive created from github, no issues there. However, if you have a friend/colleague who is also developing github, they won't be able to fetch the commons JAR anywhere and have to build commons first on their local machine again to be able to build github. Where as if you had a common repository, maven would just download the commons from there and he would have no need to build it to his local repository.